# SSIS package: Method not found Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient

Tags: azure, ssis

SSIS package

Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.AzureBlobConnectorHelper.CreateBlobClient(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)

I have installed Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS).. .but it still throws the above error while trying to run the package to download files from Blob Storage

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to change my project to target the SQL Server 2017 version. This can be found in the project's properties:

[image: ssis-azure]

I also installed the matching Azure Feature Pack:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-2017

This does not work with TLS 1.2 though, so I had to change it to 1.0. This can be setup in your azure storage account under Settings/Configuration -> Minimum TLS version.

Answer (score 0):

Just Need to Change the Target Server to 2016 in the project properties of the SSIS, it should be sufficient and to address the TLS issue , instead of downgrading to lower version and which is not safe as per the Microsoft recommendations.
We can follow these 2 simple steps to just upgrade .Net Version to circumvent the TLS downgrade.

**Use TLS 1.2**
The TLS version used by Azure Feature Pack follows system .NET Framework settings. To use TLS 1.2, add a REG_DWORD value named SchUseStrongCrypto with data 1 under the following two registry keys.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

Answer (score -1):

Basically ,The Azure Blob Download Task enables an SSIS package to download files from [Azure Blob Storage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-blob-download-task?view=sql-server-ver15)

> To add an  **Azure Blob Download Task**, drag-drop it to the SSIS
> Designer, and double-click or right-click and click  **Edit**  to see
> the following  **Azure Blob Download Task Editor**  dialog box.

Method not found exception could be the reason of versions of SSIS that you are using.
Follow the  [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/245795/method-not-found-39microsoftanalysisservicedatabas.html) for conversation going on with similar issues.

For further related issues check this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-integration-runtime-ssis-activity-faq).